# cURL download file issues

Tags: php, curl, google-docs-api

I am trying to download a file from Google drive, but when I play the script, it gives me following error:

```
Moved Temporarily

The document has moved here.
```

My code is given below:

```
$source = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B8tmy5YxFFGhM0szSUZWVl9qQWc&export=download";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
echo $data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $error = curl_error($ch); 


//print_r($ch);


$destination = "data.csv";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function gett($url) {
$url = str_replace(" ", '%20', $url);
fopen("cookies.txt", "w");
$parts = parse_url($url);
$host = $parts['host'];
$ch = curl_init($url);
$header = Array('Connection:keep-alive',
'Proxy-Connection: Close',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1017.2 Safari/535.19',
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
'Connection: Close');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_REQUEST['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}
```

use this function .it will work

[to know About Curl read this blog](https://codingtube.tech/2023/01/12/php/what-is-curl-in-php-with-example/)

Comment: Can you explain further why this will work? Which are the crucial parts in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're receiving a redirect. You can ask curl to follow redirects with the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but now its' not downloading the file with teh content, now its getting the html page of google login in .csv file..:( i need to download the exact content as it is in $source, copy that link and than download the file and than see i want to get the exact .csv file.

Comment: @DeDevelopers Google drive docs require a login to download. You'll need to have the curl script send the username and password and store the cookie that is returned.

Comment: but i dont want to login, is there any other way to download that file without login because its a client work, whenever, he will click on update this file will be donwloaded and update in database..

Comment: @DeDevelopers In that case you will need to make the document public. Be warned though it means anyone can download it using the URL.

Comment: Okay that's not a issue, how can i make the file public any idea? i am new in this

Comment: Thankyou i can now download it by making public...:)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to you curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true);
```

SO your cule code would be

```
$source = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B8tmy5YxFFGhM0szSUZWVl9qQWc&export=download";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true);
echo $data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $error = curl_error($ch);
```

That's means

> This means that libcurl will re-send the same request on the new
>   location and follow new Location:

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but now its' not downloading the file with teh content, now its getting the html page of google login in .csv file..:( i need to download the exact content as it is in $source, copy that link and than download the file and than see i want to get the exact .csv file..

Comment: yes, but i dont want to login through google, and i tried to login and it's saying you have cookies disabled on this browser, but cookies are enabled

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your script, and you should be fine.

Currently, your script just looks in the url that you are specifying, and doesnt follow the redirections. So add this, and then your script will try the url you specify in the url field, and then goes through all the redirects and returns the final data, file, or whatever that is.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but now its' not downloading the file with teh content, now its getting the html page of google login in .csv file..:( i need to download the exact content as it is in $source, copy that link and than download the file and than see i want to get the exact .csv file.

Comment: That means, you need to login to google to get what you are looking for. Make a `CURL POST` request to do the login, with `curl` set to receive and save `cookies` and then make a `get` request with those `cookies` attached.