# Download google drive file using curl command with v3 api

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

I'm looking to download file from Google drive using curl.
From their document [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
```

used

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B_ftlGgv2fEVYnp2YTczSXhVSWM?access_token=here-goes&alt=media'
```

I'm unable to get this working it returns `"Temporary Redirect The document has moved"` error message.  Though get and list curl requests are working fine.  How to use *curl* to download Google drive file with v3 api. thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Usage Problems FAQs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_tell_curl_to_follow_HTT) that:

> Curl does not follow so-called redirects by default. The Location: header that informs the client about this is only interpreted if you're using the -L/--location option. As in:
>
> `curl -L http://redirector.com`

For this, you may want to also try adding this in your code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true);
```

Using [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html) means that `libcurl` will issue another request for the new URL and follow new Location.

Lastly, you may want to also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437335/curl-download-file-issues) and see if it helps.